# Deploying package on pypi with Travis-ci fails without any error messages

Tags: python, deployment, travis-ci, continuous-deployment, pypi

I'm trying to create a continuous deployment for my Python package, and deploy the new releases of the package on Pypi using Travis-ci. I have connected the package's Github repo to Travis and I've also added the Pypi login token to it as an environment variable.

When I change something in the package and I push the changes to Github, the build starts automatically on Travis, but it fails without any error message in the log.

Here is the `travis.yml` config:

```yaml
language: python
python:
  - 3.6

deploy:
  provider: pypi
  username: "__token__"
  password: "$PYPI_TOKEN"
  on:
    branch: main
```

And here is the last lines of the build's log:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: future

  Building wheel for future (setup.py): started

  Building wheel for future (setup.py): finished with status 'done'

  Created wheel for future: filename=future-0.18.2-py3-none-any.whl size=491058 sha256=e3f69a7e2cab3dce8a3aa0d223ce834152593e789077b28d29e878118c5c8607

  Stored in directory: /home/travis/.cache/pip/wheels/6e/9c/ed/4499c9865ac1002697793e0ae05ba6be33553d098f3347fb94

Successfully built future

Installing collected packages: pytz, python-dateutil, pandas, future, chardet, urllib3, idna, requests, oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, python-twitter

Successfully installed chardet-4.0.0 future-0.18.2 idna-2.10 oauthlib-3.1.1 pandas-1.1.5 python-dateutil-2.8.1 python-twitter-3.5 pytz-2021.1 requests-2.25.1 requests-oauthlib-1.3.0 urllib3-1.26.6
```

[Full log](https://api.travis-ci.com/v3/job/521474324/log.txt)

[image: s]

What should I do to have a successful build on Pypi using Travis?

Answer (score 0):

Your Travis CI job is failing before reaching your deploy step. I would strongly recommend debugging the job [1] within VM.

[1] https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/running-build-in-debug-mode/